# Русские варианты иностранных слов. Скрапбукинг

Tags: иностранные-слова

В продолжение темы хендмейда-рукодения-ручной работы. В обсуждении пришли к выводу, что негоже употреблять англицизмы там, где можно сказать по-русски.
В комментариях я упомянула разновидность ручной работы — скрапбукинг (оформление альбомов, открыток и т.д.). Слово, как и само направление, пришло к нам из Америки, но название ни о чем не говорит (особенно тем, кто не владеет английским). Интересно, как бы это направление можно было бы обозвать по-русски? У кого какие варианты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно одно слово? Вряд ли получится, а по-русски  термин всегда объясняется как изготовление альбомов ручной работы.По-моему, всё понятно. Можно перевести слово по частям (scrapbooking: scrap — вырезка и book — книга), получится  — альбом из вырезок.(альбом = ручная книга)Туда же не только фото входят, но и разные вырезки(статьи из газет, билеты, грамоты).Как и кардмейкинг - ручное изготовление открыток. Иногда понятия совмещают, но специалисты говорят о них как о разных видах рукоделия.

Или ручное оформление альбомов и открыток.

Можно обойтись более ранним заимствованием,  оно уже привычно: ручной дизайн альбомов и открыток.

Как разговорное приемлемо альбом-самоделка, открытка-самоделка, мы их всегда так и называли, а сейчас "застыдились", потому что техника стала выше, но смысл-то тот же.

Answer (score 2):

"Альбом-самоделка", "открытка-самоделка" - прекрасные и полностью отражающие явления русские неологизмы. А застыдились мы последние 10 лет не только их, но и ВСЕХ русских слов! Потому что в нынешнем российском сознании русские слова - это слова лохов, архаизмы. Причина - в комплексе провинциализма и плебейства. Такой самоуничижающей "стыдобы" нет НИ У ОДНОГО уважающего себя народа. Вторая причина - это скудоумие. Гораздо проще тупо слизать американизм, не задумываясь о фундаментальной основе языка - коммуникативность, наплевав на тех, кто это будет непонимающе слушать или читать, втоптав в грязь культурное достоинство народа и т.д. Средство от этого языкового беспредела придумали французы 20 лет назад. В результате во французском языке с тех пор нет ни одного американизма. А необходимо всего-навсего: 1. принять закон, запрещающий в публичной сфере использовать американизмы безе перевода, 2. обязать многочисленные институты русского языка заняться СЛОВООБРАЗОВАНИЕМ русских неологизмов и публиковать ежегодно обязательные справочники для СМИ. Всё! Это безупречно работает.